# Styling <video> element in win8 app (html/js)

Tags: javascript, html, css, video, windows-8

How can I change the color of the loading progressbar, video progressbar and the volume control within a video element in a win8 application?

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the color for the progressbar in the  element.
If you want to change the color for example the "mute/volume" button, you must create self that html button.

Comment: I don't fully understand what exactly are you suggesting. Can you provide me an example code?